# How to remove credentials from URLCredentialStorage

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, keychain

I'm able to store and retrieve credentials but I'm unable to remove them. I've created a simple wrapper here but the clear method doesn't work. The credentials seem to persist after I call clear. What do I need to do to clear the credentials?

```
class PasswordManager {
    static let shared = PasswordManager() // singleton instance

    private lazy var protectionSpace: URLProtectionSpace = {
        return URLProtectionSpace(host: "somehost.com",
                                  port: 0,
                                  protocol: "http",
                                  realm: nil,
                                  authenticationMethod: nil)
    }()

    private init() { }

    func password(for userID: String) -> String? {
        guard let credentials = URLCredentialStorage.shared.credentials(for: protectionSpace) else { return nil }
        return credentials[userID]?.password
    }

    func set(password: String, for userID: String) {
        let credential = URLCredential(user: userID, password: password, persistence: .permanent)
        URLCredentialStorage.shared.set(credential, for: protectionSpace)
    }

    func clear(for userID: String) {
        if let password = password(for: userID) {
            let credential = URLCredential(user: userID, password: password, persistence: .permanent)
            URLCredentialStorage.shared.remove(credential, for: protectionSpace)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the win:

```
func clear(for userID: String) {
    guard let creds = URLCredentialStorage.shared.credentials(for: protectionSpace) else { return }
    guard let cred = creds[userID] else { return }
    URLCredentialStorage.shared.remove(cred, for: protectionSpace)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove credentials that are synchronizable, you'll have to provide an option in the remove function.

```
URLCredentialStorage.shared.remove(cred, for: protectionSpace, options: [NSURLCredentialStorageRemoveSynchronizableCredentials: true])
```

This removed credentials for me that weren't removed otherwise.